# Dplyr: efficient way to work on a subset/specific rows without altering the rest of a dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's take the following dataset:

```
df <- tibble(
  id = 1:5,
  location = rep(paste0("country", 1:2), each = 3, len = 5),
  species = paste0("species", 1:3)[rep(c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3))],
  min = c(0, 100, 0, 100, 100),
  max = c(500, 600, 700, 1100, 1100)
)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
     id location species    min   max
  <int> <chr>    <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 country1 species1     0   500
2     2 country1 species1   100   600
3     3 country1 species2     0   700
4     4 country2 species3   100  1100
5     5 country2 species3   100  1100
```

I would like to merge rows with the same species name for a specific location – say `country1` – but by keeping the lowest `min` and highest `max` values of duplicate species names.

In this example, the desired result would be:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
     id location species    min   max
  <int> <chr>    <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 country1 species1     0   600
2     3 country1 species2     0   700
3     4 country2 species3   100  1100
4     5 country2 species3   100  1100
```

The way I would normally do this would be something like:

```
country1 <- df %>% 
  filter(location == "country1") %>% 
  group_by(location, species) %>% 
  mutate(
    min = min(min),
    max = max(max)
  ) %>% 
  distinct(species, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  ungroup

df %<>% 
  filter(location != "country1") %>% 
  bind_rows(country1)

> df
# A tibble: 4 x 5
     id location species    min   max
  <int> <chr>    <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     4 country2 species3   100  1100
2     5 country2 species3   100  1100
3     1 country1 species1     0   600
4     3 country1 species2     0   700
```

But I feel like that extracting rows from the dataset, working on them separately, removing the original rows and injecting the new ones in `df` is unnecessary and redundant. I'm then wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this, with as few steps as possible.

I tried `filter(location == "country1", .preserve = TRUE)` to keep all the rows in the dataset but I didn't work. I was also thinking about using an `if_else` statement in `mutate()` to get the `min` and `max` values for each species in `country1`. But then I'd need to use `distinct()` only in rows whose location is `country1`, which I don't know how to do.

Ideally, I would like to work on a **temporary subset** of `df` where I can do all the operations I want without affecting the whole dataset.

Any idea to do what I want in a more straightforward way?

Comment: I have to think more about this, dput-sample data would be nice as well. But one tip: instead of doing group_by --> mutate --> distinct, just do group_by --> summarise and save a step.

Comment: @Fnguyen The problem with `summarise()` is that it doesn't keep all the columns of the data frame. The dataset I'm working on is much more complex that the one in the example and I do need to keep every column.

Comment: can you amend your example then? Because it is hard to guess what the output you want should look like? Does it have the same number of rows and columns as the original only with min/max adapted, then why won't mutate work?

Comment: @Fnguyen There's an example of the desired output in the question. The output should have the same number of column but different number of rows since some rows should be merged together. The problem is not about `mutate()`, which works as expected, but about all the additional and not convenient steps (e.g., extracting and removing rows from the original dataset to insert them back afterward) I have to do to get to the desired result.

Comment: I understand now, because the merging of rows is conditional to location being country1. I'll amend my answer but it will be a bit more general.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar recently so I made a function to do what I wanted.

```
library(tidyverse)

transform_subset <- function(.data, ..., .fun) {
  bind_rows(
    filter(.data, !(!!!rlang::enquos(...))),
    .fun(filter(.data, ...))
  )
}

df %>% 
  transform_subset(
    location == "country1",
    .fun = function(x) {
      x %>% 
        group_by(location, species) %>% 
        mutate(
          min = min(min),
          max = max(max)
        ) %>% 
        distinct(species, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
        ungroup
    }
  )

# # A tibble: 4 x 5
# id location species    min   max
# <int> <chr>    <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4 country2 species3   100  1100
# 2     5 country2 species3   100  1100
# 3     1 country1 species1     0   600
# 4     3 country1 species2     0   700
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with your sample data and produces the output at the end:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(location,species) %>%
  summarise(min = min(min), max = max(max))
```

Edit after Update:

To shorten your workflow I can think of two options:

1. Transform data in place:

Instead of saving data externally you can simply mutate in-place like this:

```
df %>%
filter(location !="country1") %>%
bind_rows((df %>% filter(location ==...)), by = "location") # replace ... with full transformation from above
```

2. Use a function

This strategy becomes even more efficient if combined with a function, like this:

```
merge_rows <- function(df,target){
df %>%
filter(location == target) %>% 
  group_by(location, species) %>% 
  mutate(
    min = min(min),
    max = max(max)
  ) %>% 
  distinct(species, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  ungroup
}

df %>%
filter(location !="country1") %>%
bind_rows((merge_rows(df), by = "location")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not keep all the columns of the dataset and will also merge rows in `country2`, which is not what I want.